# Why the drawPolygon method in Graphics Class abstract and I can still use it

Tags: java, swing

In [Graphics Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29), there is an **abstract** method defined as

```
public abstract void drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)
```

Why do I still be able to use the method directly in my code?

**EDIT:**
In the Official java documentation, the only **Direct Known Subclasses** of `Graphics` is `Graphics2D`, which doesn't implement the method, and doesn't have any **Direct Known Subclasses**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can still use it because you are not actually using the abstract class Graphics in your code.  Your application will be using a concrete subclass of Graphics, which is passed to methods such as `paintComponent(Graphics)`.  This concrete subclass will have `drawPolygon(int[], int[], int)` implemented.

This [lesson](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) on painting in Swing may help provide more details on how these methods work.  The article [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/) will also be useful.

Comment: No, I am using `g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, numPoints);` directly inside the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method I defined.

Comment: @23hush - right, but the framework created and passed the instance of graphics to your application.  You didn't create it.  If you do `System.out.println(g.getClass().getName());` what does it output?

Comment: @23hush: Read carefully. @Justkt gave you CORRECT answer. You may need to learn about polymorphism and inheritance.

Comment: @eugener, @Justkt: I figured out that the Class of the object passed to the method is `SunGraphics2D`, which is not mentioned anywhere in the official java api documentation. I think that might be a platform-specific thing and could be different if I am using another Java VM. Am I correct?